# How to query mongoDB with $elemMatch using mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I have this document in mongodb

```
{
  "_id": "3ca85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66af33",
  "allowedNssaiList": [
    {
      "allowedSnssaiList": [
        {
          "allowedSnssai": {
            "sst": 1,
            "sd": "2"
          },
          "IMSI": "2443800000001",
          "tac": "3022",
          "zone": "zone1",
          "_id": "1"
        }
      ],
      "accessType": "3GPP_ACCESS"
    }
  ]
}
```

When using mgo-driver the below find query command works

```
pipeline := bson.M{"allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"allowedSnssai.sst": 1, "allowedSnssai.sd": "2"}},
        "tac": "3022"}
```

Now that i have change to use mongo-driver, am getting index error. 
runtime error: index out of range

```
pipeline := bson.M{"allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"allowedSnssai.sst": 1, "allowedSnssai.sd": "2"}},
        "tac": "3022"}
cur, err := db.Collection(COLLECTION).Find(ctx, pipeline)
```

I tried on mongodb command line this command below and it works as well

```
db.slicecoll.find( { "allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList": { $elemMatch: { "allowedSnssai.sst" : 1,"allowedSnssai.sd" : "2", "tac":"3022"}}}).pretty()
```

but it's bson.M form does not work and am getting the same error as above

```
    pipeline := bson.M{"allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"allowedSnssai.sst": 1, "allowedSnssai.sd": "2", "tac": "3022"}}}
```

Any idea how to find this document in my collection that matches all the three values.

Comment: I tried with a collection with just the doc you provided and with the last way to build the pipeline you showed, it worked fine for me. Does the `out of range` error point to the line with `.Find()`? Are you executing it in a collection with only that document or do you have more docs inserted?

Comment: The out of range error ocurr  when i use the bson.M formats, the pipeline lines in the db.Collection(COLLECTION).Find(ctx, pipeline). And I think the errors are point to the pipeline variables. Am executing it in a collection with only a single document.